# How can I save the last opened files for each active project?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

How can I save the last opened files form a specific project, so when next time opened, aptana will reopen those files automatically again for me?

I am not sure if I looked well, but I can't find such option in aptana studio 3 on my ubuntu 12.04 version. Is there any extension that could help me?

The Version is Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137

Thank you

Comment: Mine does this automatically, I'll have a look through the preferences and see if there's a setting.

Answer (score 1):

OK in regards to my previous comment..

In the preferences dialog (Window > Preferences) go to:

General > Editors

And make sure that the `Restore editor state on startup` option is checked.

Comment: what version is yours?

Comment: Actually yes, the last project that was opened when the editor was closed will be kept. However, if you close the project by right click close project on the project explorer tree and then reopen it, the state will be lost